# Change useRef value before the html renders (React Functional Component)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

Hey everyone i trying to change the value of useRef before the html renders I tried to do that in useEffect but useEffect runs after the html is ready so can't use useEffect
So what i am trying to do is reset the value of **ultiDayPlaceHFactor** variable value to 0 before the html renders because i am updating the value of **ultiDayPlaceHFactor** for next or previous week events

below is that code Please check it out

````
const Week = ({ events, weekDates, currentDate, toggle }: Props) => {
  const { startHour: START_HOUR, endHour: END_HOUR } = useStore();

  const [multiDayEvents, setMultiDayEvents] = useState<any[]>([]);
  const [showAllMultiDEvents, setShowMultiDEvents] = useState<boolean>(false);
  // const [multiDPlaceHeight, setMultiDHeight] = useState<number>(0);

  const hours = eachMinuteOfInterval(
    {
      start: new Date(new Date().setHours(START_HOUR)).setMinutes(0),
      end: new Date(new Date().setHours(END_HOUR)).setMinutes(0),
    },
    { step: 60 }
  );


  const multiDayPlaceHFactor = useRef(0);
  const computeMultiDPHeight = (val: number) => {
    return val > 2 && !showAllMultiDEvents ? 3 * 28 : val * 28;
  };

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   multiDayPlaceHFactor.current = 0;
  //   // eventsIndexes.current = [];

  //   console.log('------------------------------------');
  //   console.log(multiDayPlaceHFactor, 'Height factor');
  //   // console.log(eventsIndexes, 'event indexes');
  // }, [weekDates, showAllMultiDEvents]);

  console.log(multiDayPlaceHFactor, 'height factor');

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="w-100">
        <div id="day-layout-table" className="mt-3">
          <table className="e-schedule-table border mb-0">
            <tbody>
              <tr>
              
                <td>
                  <div className="e-date-header-container">
                    <div className="e-date-header-wrapper">
                      <table className="e-schedule-table">
                        <colgroup>
                          <col></col>
                          <col></col>
                          <col></col>
                          <col></col>
                          <col></col>
                          <col></col>
                          <col></col>
                        </colgroup>
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            {(weekDates || []).map((e) => {
                              const today = e;
                              const eachFirstDayInCalcRow = isSameDay(
                                weekDates[0],
                                today
                              )
                                ? today
                                : null;
                              const todayEvents = events.filter(
                                (e: {
                                  startDate: number | Date;
                                  endDate: number | Date;
                                }) =>
                                  (eachFirstDayInCalcRow &&
                                    areIntervalsOverlapping(
                                      {
                                        start: e.startDate,
                                        end: e.endDate,
                                      },
                                      {
                                        start: startOfDay(today),
                                        end: endOfDay(today),
                                      }
                                    ) &&
                                    differenceInDaysOmitTime(
                                      new Date(e.startDate),
                                      new Date(e.endDate)
                                    ) > 1) ||
                                  (isSameDay(e.startDate, today) &&
                                    differenceInDaysOmitTime(
                                      new Date(e.startDate),
                                      new Date(e.endDate)
                                    ) > 1)
                              );

                              // console.log(todayEvents, 'today events');

                              const prevNextEvents = events.filter((e) => {
                                const isWithinToday =
                                  areIntervalsOverlapping(
                                    {
                                      start: e.startDate,
                                      end: e.endDate,
                                    },
                                    {
                                      start: startOfDay(today),
                                      end: endOfDay(today),
                                    }
                                  ) &&
                                  differenceInDaysOmitTime(
                                    e.startDate,
                                    e.endDate
                                  ) > 1;

                                return isWithinToday;
                              });

                              ///////////////////////////////// 
                              /////////////////////////////////
                              / HERE IS THE UPDATE VALUE CODE /
                              ///////////////////////////////// 
                              /////////////////////////////////
                              if (
                                prevNextEvents.length >
                                multiDayPlaceHFactor.current
                              )
                                multiDayPlaceHFactor.current =
                                  prevNextEvents.length;
                              /////////////////////////////////
                              /////////////////////////////////
                              / HERE IS THE UPDATE VALUE CODE /
                              ///////////////////////////////// 
                              /////////////////////////////////

                              let eventsIndexes: any = [];

                              return (
                                <td
                                  className="e-all-day-appointment-wrapper"
                                  key={uuid()}
                                >
                                  <RenderMultidayEvents
                                    multiDayEvents={todayEvents}
                                    prevNextEvents={prevNextEvents}
                                    showMultiDEvents={showAllMultiDEvents}
                                    eventsIndexes={eventsIndexes}
                                    weekStart={startOfDay(weekDates[0])}
                                    weekEnd={endOfDay(
                                      weekDates[weekDates.length - 1]
                                    )}
                                  />
                                  {prevNextEvents.length > 2 &&
                                    !showAllMultiDEvents && (
                                      <div className="px-1">
                                        <button
                                          onClick={() =>
                                            setShowMultiDEvents(
                                              !showAllMultiDEvents
                                            )
                                          }
                                          className="e-more-indicator fs-7 btn btn-secondary p-1 w-100 text-start position-absolute"
                                          data-count="1"
                                          data-group-index="0"
                                          style={{
                                            top: `${3 * 32}px`,
                                            left: 0,
                                          }}
                                        >
                                          +{prevNextEvents.length - 2}&nbsp;more
                                        </button>
                                      </div>
                                    )}
                                </td>
                              );
                            })}
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                          <tr></tr>
                          <tr className="e-header-row">
                            {(weekDates || []).map((date, i) => (
                              <td
                                colSpan={1}
                                key={uuid()}
                                className={
                                  isSameDay(date, currentDate)
                                    ? 'fw-normal text-center align-middle text-Capitalize text-primary border-start'
                                    : 'fw-normal text-center align-middle text-Capitalize border-start'
                                }
                                style={{ width: '116.6px' }}
                              >
                                <div className="e-header-cells">
                                  {format(date, 'd EEE')}
                                </div>
                              </td>
                            ))}
                          </tr>
                          <tr className="e-all-day-cells">
                            {(weekDates || []).map((e) => {
                              return (
                                <td
                                  key={uuid()}
                                  style={{
                                    height: `${computeMultiDPHeight(
                                      multiDayPlaceHFactor.current
                                    )}px`,
                                  }}
                                  className="border-start"
                                >
                                  <div></div>
                                </td>
                              );
                            })}
                          </tr>
                        </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td>
                  <div
                    style={{ height: DEFAULT_SHEDULAR_HEIGHT }}
                    className="e-time-cells-wrap"
                  >
                    <table>
                      <tbody>
                        {(hours || []).map((time, idx) => (
                          <tr key={uuid()}>
                            <td
                              style={{ height: CELL_HEIGHT }}
                              className="calendar-td calendar-td-w border-top py-0 align-middle"
                            >
                              <span className="fs-7">
                                {format(time, 'h:mm a', { locale: enUS })}
                              </span>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                        ))}
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div
                    style={{ height: DEFAULT_SHEDULAR_HEIGHT }}
                    className="e-content-wrap"
                  >
                    <table className="e-schedule-table">
                      <colgroup>
                        <col></col>
                        <col></col>
                        <col></col>
                        <col></col>
                        <col></col>
                        <col></col>
                        <col></col>
                      </colgroup>
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          {(weekDates || []).map((date, i) => (
                            <td
                              key={uuid()}
                              className="e-day-wrapper overflow-visible"
                            >
                              <div className="e-appointment-wrapper">
                                <RenderEvents
                                  day={date}
                                  events={getAppointmentsByDates(date, events)}
                                />
                              </div>
                            </td>
                          ))}
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        {(hours || []).map((time, idx) => (
                          <tr key={idx}>
                            {(weekDates || []).map((date) => (
                              <td
                                key={uuid()}
                                aria-label={date.toISOString()}
                                style={{ height: CELL_HEIGHT }}
                                className="calendar-td calendar-td-w border-start border-top text-nowrap day-time-w fs-8 py-0 align-middle"
                              ></td>
                            ))}
                          </tr>
                        ))}
                      </tbody>
                    </table>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};```
````

[image: Code]
[image: Implementation]

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: If useState is not an option, then you could try using a simple useRef BUT update the component ONCE after the first render to update values. You can do so using a combination of useState and useEffect:

```
const [updateState, setUpdateState] = useState(true);
const update = () => {setUpdateState(!updateState)};
// this sets up the update function which, when called,
// simply updates the component

useEffect(() => {
  update();
},[]);
// this will call the update function ONCE
// after the initial render of the component
```

In short, this code triggers a single component re-render AFTER the initial render.

Such a technique is often used in cases where a value changes during the first rendering and is required in multiple areas, some before the change takes place, and using a state is not an option, just like in your case.

> Mate, it's kinda hard to understand what exactly you actually need, I
> see no place where you change the value of `multiDayPlaceHFactor`
> before the first render, you only change it while rendering, it
> already should be 0 before first render because of `= useRef(0)`. You
> can initialize a Ref with whatever you want, but if you really need to
> change it AFTER initializing it but before first render, just do it in
> the root of your Week component function, any code before the return
> will get executed before the render. The same applies if you need to
> reset it before the `render ( <td...` part, just use set it to 0
> before the `render`. If you meant something else, do get back and I'll
> try to help you

Comment: Hello Isidor thankyou for you reply and the will to help sorry for replying late i was busy in my papers. I can't share the logic here in text but i'll update my question you would be able to see it in visual please check question their you will more details are added Thank you : )

Comment: Hmm... I see. Is there any particular reason why you're not using useState? It should do what you need. It will initially render the first td with height 0, yes, BUT after changing it's value in thead it will trigger a component re-render and all td-s will have the correct height

Comment: Yeah i thought about that as well but using "useState" in this case, means in map function can trigger infinite loop of component rerendering, and hence react will throw an error that's why can't use useState in this case have thing about something else.

Comment: I see, try the useEffect solution i added in the response and let me know if it works

Comment: useEffect is good for this kind of stuff but useEffect runs after the html in rendered so it just won't work as i am not using useState so the component does not rerenders.

Comment: That's why we use the update() function which will trigger a component reload. I placed the entire code that you need to add to the beginning of your component, in the answer. Try it out